# Team Foundation Server Using Custom Fields instead of System Fields

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I'm introducing TFS 2010 in our company.
After a lot of work on item customizations, I'm considering using custom fields as some system fields.

One example...

I've got some management requirements for the field "System.priority". This field should be set to "REQUIRED", so everyone has to do an estimation about the priority of a bug or task.

Are there  any well known problems with creating an custom mypriority field and using it? (except the whole customizing afterwards for the basic reports...)
I know i cant delete the system fields but i can delete the references for system.priority from the layout tab and then im going to use my own customized ones ..

Is this possible?

Comment: When im opening my work item field explorer, i have only a field called " Microsoft.VSTS.Common.priority" and for this field it is not possible to set it mandatory.

Beside that, how can i compose those "custom rules"? I never seen a "new rule" button or something like that in the field definition.

Comment: You want to have as few mandatory fields initially. You can enforce the requiredness of any field in the transition from proposed to the state that represents that it was accepted. Otherwise you won't be able to start tracking requirements that are not well defined enough yet.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid creating custom fields when the default ones can serve the purpose. E.g.: Use the **[REQUIRED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404861)** rule where needed:

```
<FIELD name="Priority" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority" type="Integer" reportable="dimension">
  <REQUIRED />    
</FIELD>
```

Comment: Have you ever tried that yourself?
it is not possible to do that... tfs will tell you that this system field cant be set to "REQUIRED"

Comment: Sure. While there are some fields which have rules restrictions such as the Area and Iteration, the Priority field is not one of them.